# PostgreSQL various clean up of string \ varchar

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have to clean up some varchar in the following manner:

1. Remove special characters such as: `!, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), }, {, [, ], ",", ., ?, /, ',` from a closed list. I've managed to do so with a mass use of replace\regexp_replace but I'm looking for something similar to the one in SQL server.
2. Remove following numbers but not adjacent ones meaning:

   `round 1 --> round`
   `round1 --> round1`
   `round 12345 --> round`
   `round12345 --> round12345`
3. Remove words out of a closed list of words such as: **"and", "or", "Ltd.", "international"** without substrings:

   `more food or drinks ---> more food drinks. and not --> me food or drinks`

I'm working on a big table and I'd like to do it as efficient as possible.
Should I write a function that does that or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Your 3rd question is not well defined btw. The dot in 'Ltd.' could be the dot ending a sentence or the dot after an abbreviation.

Comment: You're correct, "." shouldn't be in (3.) since it was removed in (1.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter and Tometzky thank you both. I wished I could tick all answers as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll play along. Here's for **question 2**:

```
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(
   '12 foo1 run 1457 ABC 1Foo 2456 bar 34',
   '\s*\m\d+\M\s*',
   ' ',
   'g'
   ));
```

Returns:

```
foo1 run ABC 1Foo bar
```

I updated the answer to use *constraint expressions* instead of the *bracket expressions*, because the manual informs:

> The constraint escapes described below are usually preferable; they
>   are no more standard, but are easier to type.

`\s*` ..  zero or more white space
`\m` .. beginning of a word (same as `[[:<:]]`)
`\d+` .. 1 or more digits
`\M` .. end of a word (same as `[[:>:]]`)

The 4th parameter `'g'` is needed to replace "globally", not just the first occurrence.

[->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/408) for v9.2
[->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/d41d8/29) for v8.4 doesn't work

#### Why?

[`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS). The default changed with v9.1.

*This* works in both worlds, "compatibility mode" so to say. But the syntax of the modern version above (in combination with `standard_conforming_strings = on`) is cleaner.

```
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(
  '12 foo1 run 1457 ABC 1Foo 2456 bar 34',
  E'\\s*\\m\\d+\\M\\s*',
  ' ',
  'g'
));
```

[->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/d41d8/30)

Comment: I've corrected Erwin's answer, because it would leave numbers at a start and end of the string.

Comment: @Tometzky: Thanks, and I cleaned up the white space.

Comment: I'm afraid this one doesn't work. I'm still getting 
'12 foo1 run 1457 ABC 1Foo 2456 bar 34' out of it. could it be the postgresql version that I'm using (8.2.15)?

Comment: @gilibi: I added an explanation, demo and another version.

Comment: I figured it out as well a minute ago: '\d+' should be '\\d+' thanks

Comment: @gilibi: Cool. As an aside: v8.2 has reached EOL in 2011. You *need* to upgrade to a more current version. Barring that, you should at least upgrade to the last point-release 8.2.23, which can be done in place without dump / restore. Consider http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 4):

1.
It is much better to replace character which are not in allowed list with spaces, like this:

```
select regexp_replace(
    E'aśx€ ąsd, dsa w|adwf\n  as dw dgaa[aw] asdd',
    '[^a-zA-Z0-9]',
    ' ',
    'g');
```

This returns

```
a x   sd  dsa w adwf   as dw dgaa aw  asdd
```

There are thousands of possible characters in Unicode — it isn't really possible to list all *special* characters.

Taking out multiple consecutive spaces left as exercise to the reader.

Comment: Multiple questions need multiple answers. This is an answer for question 1.

Comment: Actually: multiple questions shouldn't be put into a single question.

Answer (score 2):

3.
I think the fastest way would be:

```
select regexp_replace(
  'And more food or drinks at the international airport Ltd',
  '[[:<:]](and|or|Ltd|international)[[:>:]]',
  ' ',
  'gi'
);
```

This returns:

```
 more food  drinks at the  airport
```

I assume that `Ltd.` really is `Ltd`, as a dot is filtered out in first answer.