# Using postgres regexp_replace to replace a list of strings by always the same string

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, replace, character

Hi i would like to use regexp_replace (or any other postgres function if reasonable) to replace characters in a string by a '', i.e. erase them.

Using regexp_replace(('def4abcdef4ab','4', '','g') i can replace/erase all  occurrences of '4', but i want to also replace all occurences of 'e' and b' in the same process, without using several nested processes like  regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace())).

i.e. i want to be able to provide a short list of different strings which then should be replace by a unique string.

Any ideas? Thanks a  lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok found out the answer myself (helped by [PostgreSQL various clean up of string \ varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412635/postgresql-various-clean-up-of-string-varchar)):

```
select regexp_replace(
E'aśx€ ąsd, dsa w|adwf\n  YZas dw dgaa[aw] asdd',
'[^a-zA-Y0-9 ]',
'',
'g');
```

Answer (score 32):

The canonical way is to use character classes, like so,

```
regexp_replace('def4abcdef4ab','[4eb]', '','g')
```

though @alexius's method can also handle strings.

Not sure if perhaps non-greedily quantifying the expression would make it more efficient, *e.g.* `[4eb]+?`.

Answer (score 8):

`regexp_replace('def4abcdef4ab','4|e|b', '','g')`

Answer (score 8):

You don't need regular expressions for single character replacement Use the translate function, ie

```
translate('def4abcdef4ab','4eb', '')
```

If your strings are multiple characters long, then use replace(). Even nested, this would likely give better performance than regular expressions.